# How to correctly deploy an S3 static website using GoogleDomains and R53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I cannot succesfully deploy my static website from S3.

I've followed AWS Guides, YouTube videos but nothing seems to work. Here's my setup:

S3 buckets with names equal to my domain and (www.) subdomain.
[image]
[image]
[image]
If I try to go into the S3 website I can see my page:
[image]
www. subdomain bucket as redirect request as `http`:
[image]

My hosted zone with properly created records (I believe)
[image]
Then changed my custom domains from `domains.google.com` to fit the ones in the NS record from the Hosted Zone:

[image]

But when I try to go into my domain I get a TimeOut error...
[image]

Tutorials that I've followed:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html
- https://awstip.com/launching-your-s3-website-using-aws-route-53-cloudfront-and-your-3rd-party-registered-domain-name-9193ef1d1cac

If I try to edit the A records with my complete S3 website URL, this is what I see:
[image]

If I try to input it manually I get an error message:
[image]

### Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual option is to combine S3 and Cloudfront, so that you get best global performance and also well named HTTPS URLs. This will also sort out permissions for you. It involves these steps:

- Upload static content to S3
- Create a Cloufront distribution that maps to the content
- Cloudfront distributes content globally and gives you a generated HTTPS URL
- Route 53 emables you to expose the Cloudfront URL with a custom domain name
- Use Cloudfront lambdas to fine tune behaviour, such as serving index.html for all paths

For a walkthrough and further details, see  [my blog posts](https://authguidance.com/cdn-static-content-delivery/). There is a code sample there also, which might provide some useful hints. My scenario is a secured SPA though, so some of it may not be relevant to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Route53 DNS records value starts with `s3-website-...` - it looks like you omitted the unique prefix of the S3 website URL.

Comment: If I try to add the unique prefix of my s3 website URL, aws will display only the current value. I've edited the question so you can see.

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume:

- Your domain name (hostzone name) in route53 is `example.com`
- Your bucket name is `test.example.com`
- Your bucket is publicly accessible
- You've enabled static website hosting and the endpoint is `http://test.example.com.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`

Ensure below things:

- The record name should match the bucket name, if your bucket name is `test.example.com`, your subdomain should be `test`, if your bucket name is `example.com`, leave the subdomain empty.
- The region under `Route traffic to` should match the region in your static site endpoint.
- Then if you've enabled static website hosting, you'll get a suggestion under S3 Endpoint as `s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com (test.example.com)`, and value `s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com` will be set if you choose that option.

By following the above steps, you can resolve this issue.

Comment: As mentioned in the title and description I do not own a domain in Route53, I'm using Google Domains. I have a Hosted Zone in R53 with the same name of my google domain.

Comment: Yeah, the above solution applies for that, I've tested this case.